# Java - Generating random expression with the pre-set answer

Tags: java

I'm making an Android app which will do the following:

- Generate the random number (1-9) and save it
- Generate the expression the answer of which is the previous step
- Show the expression and a "numpad" with numbers from 1 to 9 on it
- Wait for user to press one of the buttons on numpad and check if it's correct
- If user chose the wrong answer generate a new expression for the same number as before (step 2)
- If user chose the right answer go to step 1

So now I'm creating a method which will generate the expression:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int number = rnd.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String example = expressionGeneration(number);

        System.out.println(example);

    }

    private static String expressionGeneration(int a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        char op = '$'; // to make it initialized and recognize mistakes
        int x;
        double y = 0.5;

        do {
            int choice = rnd.nextInt(7);
            x = rnd.nextInt(100);
            switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                y = a + x;
                op = '-';
                break;
            case 1:
                y = a - x;
                op = '+';
                break;
            case 2:
                y = a * x;
                op = '/';
                break;
            case 3:
                x = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
                y = a / x;
                op = '*';
                break;
            case 4:
                y = Math.pow(a, 2); // will be changed later to display the result right
                op = '√';
                break;
            case 5:
                if (Math.sqrt(a) % 1 == 0) {
                    y = Math.sqrt(a);
                    op = '^';
                    x = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 6:         //it's a joke   
                if (x == 33) {
                    return "33";
                }
                y = 0.5;    //to regenerate if (x != 33)
                break;
            }
        } while ((int) y != y); //to check if y is integer and if no - regenerate

        sb.append((int) y + "" + op + "" + x + "=" + a); // answer here is just for testing

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Most of the time it gives me exactly what I need, for example: "-8+11=3", but sometimes it gives examples like this ones:

1. 0$92=3
2. 0*40=8

I think this means multiplying doesn't work right and in some case op and y are not initialized in a loop, but how is it possible?
Or maybe you could suggest any other algorithm that will work in my case.

**So my question is: what am I doing wrong and are there other ways of doing what I need?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing with `/` using two integers, the result will always be an integer, even if the variable the result is stored in is a `double`. To fix this, you need to explicitly state that one of the numbers in the division is a `double`.

```
case 3:
    x = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
    y = a / (double) x;
    op = '*';
    break;
```